# Getting values from multiple fragments with universal button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-bundle

I'm pretty new to android programming so i'm sorry if the question is stupid. I've tried searching and watching multiple youtube tutorials but couldn't find anything to answer my question.

So what I have now are multiple fragments with 5 radiogroups each. I got to the point where I can get the app to calculate and display the "score" for the radiobuttons selected. But I would like to include a single button that can take in all these radiobuttons and calculate the score for all fragments at once instance. Would bundles be the way to go? If so how can I make a button that submits everything at once?

I'm attaching the code for my fragment:

```
package se.example.bevarade;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DukadeBordFragment extends Fragment {
    int dukadeScore;
    View view;

    public DukadeBordFragment(){
        // Empty public constructor
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dukade_bord, container, false);

        Button subbeBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        subbeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
                dukadeScore = checkAnswers();
                displayFinalScore(dukadeScore);

            }
        });

        return view;

    }
    public int checkAnswers() {

        /* Question One - The correct answer is RadioButton q14*/
        RadioButton dukq1a = view.findViewById(R.id.duk_q1rb_alt1);
        boolean dukQue1 = dukq1a.isChecked();
        if (dukQue1) {
            dukadeScore += 1;
        }
        /* Question Two - The correct answer is RadioButton q14*/
        RadioButton dukq2a = view.findViewById(R.id.duk_q2rb_alt1);
        boolean dukQue2 = dukq2a.isChecked();
        if (dukQue2) {
            dukadeScore += 1;
        }
        /* Question Three - The correct answer is RadioButton q14*/
        RadioButton dukq3a = view.findViewById(R.id.duk_q3rb_alt1);
        boolean dukQue3 = dukq3a.isChecked();
        if (dukQue3) {
            dukadeScore += 1;
        }
        /* Question Four - The correct answer is RadioButton q14*/
        RadioButton dukq4a = view.findViewById(R.id.duk_q4rb_alt1);
        boolean dukQue4 = dukq4a.isChecked();
        if (dukQue4) {
            dukadeScore += 1;
        }
        /* Question Five - The correct answer is RadioButton q14*/
        RadioButton dukq5a = view.findViewById(R.id.duk_q5rb_alt1);
        boolean dukQue5 = dukq5a.isChecked();
        if (dukQue5) {
            dukadeScore += 1;
        }


        return dukadeScore;
    }


    private void displayFinalScore(int score){
        TextView scoreView = view.findViewById(R.id.score_text);
        scoreView.setText(getString(R.string.you_scored) + score    + getString(R.string.out_of_total));

        dukadeScore = 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: All of your fragment are showing on the screen at the same time or is it coming one by one ? And you want all buttons' result at one click at end of page is it ?

Comment: Yes they are showing one page at the time, correct would like to get the result at the end which could either be displayed in a fragment or a seperate activity whichever is easier

Comment: Save the user response and then calculate result at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data through bundle fragment by fragment, and calculate it at the end IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solution to this,

1. Pass results in bundle from one fragment to other
2. Create application level public array or something which will hold data
   till the flow completes
3. Create activity variable - static which will store all fragments data.

But you need to deinitalize it once calculation is done.